# when use sum() in a query without result return null

Tags: mysql

when use `sum()` in a query without result return null row

for example i have this table :

```
 | id | name | visit | active |

 | 1  | ali |  4   |    0   |

 | 2  | ali |  8   |    0   |
```

and i run this query :

```
select name, sum(visit) visit

from table 

where active = 1
```

Because this query is not result

return this :

```
| name | visit |

| null | null  |
```

I do not want any row in the result

can i Solve the problem with sql way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, sum(visit)
from table 
where active = 1
group by name
having sum(visit) is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name, SUM(active = 1) visit_cnt
FROM yourTable;
```

This way, your application will consistently receive a single row containing the visit count, which would be zero or greater.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tmp.* from
(
    select name, sum(visit) as visit
    from table 
    where active = 1
) as tmp
where tmp.visit is not null
```